# Can a voltage higher than 5V be applied to the 28BYJ-48 (5V) stepper motor?

Tags: voltage, stepper-motor, driver, overheat

I want to automate my roller blinds by using an ESP (NodeMCU) and I was thinking of using a stepper motor.
I had a 28BYJ-48(5V) stepper motor laying around with the ULN2003 driver it came with.
Unfornltunately the torque is not high enough to roll the blinds up. I tried applying 7.5V to the driver and now the torque is enough.
The stepoer motor does not much hotter than when I'm applying 5V to it.
My question is: how bad or unsafe is it to apply a voltage higher than 5V to the motor?

Comment: are you certain that you actually applied 5 V? ... did you measure the voltage at the motor?

Comment: What about the current? How much current does the motor draw on 5V and 7.5V?

Comment: @jstola, I found out that instead of 5V I was applying 6V and instead of 7.5V I was applying 8.5V.

Comment: This is not an application where you want to use a stepper.  You want a DC gearmotor.  That said, steppers are current mode devices not voltage ones and best driven from a chopping driver using several times the rated current voltage to overcome winding inductance.

Comment: I think using a stepper motor is the way to go because it an then keep track of the location of the blinds.